# CKEditor - Plugin "ImageUploader" - problema no link da imagem

Tags: php, plugin, ckeditor

Eu consigo fazer o upload da imagem, ele sobe a imagem corretamente e mostra no editor. Ja verifiquei via FTP e o arquivo esta subindo para a pasta corretamente.

Quando eu envio o formulário para a outra pagina, a imagem não aparece mais e o caminho fica todo esquisito.

Alguém sabe o que fazer?

por exemplo:
a minha pasta de uploads atual é a

> ckeditor/plugins/imageuploader/uploads

Porém quando o formulário é enviado, a imagem não aparece mais e olhando o código fonte o caminho que aparece é :

> src=\"ckeditor/plugins/imageuploader/../../../ckeditor/plugins/imageuploader/uploads/398e273.jpg\"

Comment: coloque os códigos que você utiliza para que possamos analisar.